# No results returned for filtered Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having trouble executing the following request against Elasticsearch v2.2.0. If I remove the `filter` property (and contents, of course), I get my entity back (only one exists). With the `filter` clause in place, I just get 0 results, but no error. Same if I remove the `email` filter and/or the `name` filter. Am I doing something wrong with this request?

**Request**

```
GET http://localhost:9200/my-app/my-entity/_search?pretty=1

{
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "email": "my.email@email.com"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "name": "Test1"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Existing Entity**

```
{
    "email": "my.email@email.com",
    "name": "Test1"
}
```

**Mapping**

```
"properties": {
    "name": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "term": {
        "type": "long"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the mapping of your index. `GET /my-app/my-entity/_mapping`.

Comment: It probably indicates that your `email` field is analyzed (and thus split in two tokens, `my.email` and `email.com`), and/or that your `name` field is analyzed as well and thus the uppercase `T` kills the match, i.e. use `test1` instead of `Test1`

Comment: @Richa Added mapping to OP.

Comment: @Val Even if I filter on another field (e.g. `name`), I still get zero results. I tried both cases with no luck.

Comment: @josh M. You mean `{
                        "term": {
                            "name": "Test1"
                        }
                    }`. this is not working

Comment: Try `{ "term": { "name": "test1" } }` (i.e. all lowercase), what do you get?

Comment: @Richa @Val Doing a simple filter with "test1" lower-case works -- `{ "query": { "filtered": { "filter": { "term": { "name": "test1" } } } } }`. Using `Test1`, the query returns no results -- which makes little sense to me since the model itself has a name of `Test1`, even as it's returned from Elasticsearch. Also, doing this same query as a single-term `and` filter, works if it's lower case. But I still can't get anything to come back when filtering by `email`.

Comment: @josh: As mentioned by Val, `email` field would get split up as it is analyzed. By default all string fields are analysed using `standard analyzer`. If you want to match exact term, you need to make your field `not_analyzed`.

Comment: @Richa, I don't understand why I can't still do a full search on the email field. Can you point me to some documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

Since `email` field is `analyzed` with no `custom analyzer`, [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) will get applied to it and it will split into tokens.
Read about [Standard Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/standard-tokenizer.html) here.

You can use below command to see how `my.email@email.com` is getting tokenized.

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=standard" -d "my.email@email.com".
```

This will generate following output.

```
{
 "tokens": [
  {
     "token": "my.email",      ===> Notice this
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 8,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 1
  },
  {
     "token": "email.com",     ===> Notice this
     "start_offset": 9,
     "end_offset": 17,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 2
    }
   ]
}
```

If you want full or exact search you need to make it `not_analyzed`. Study about how to create a `not_analyzed` field [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html).

```
{
"email": {
    "type":     "string",
    "index":    "not_analyzed"
 }
}
```

Hope it is clear

Comment: I'm looking into this and understand what you're saying. However, it seems really unintuitive that an analyzed field wouldn't include the entire field in addition to the tokens. I see that I can use the `uax_url_email` tokenizer, and am working on learning about that. :)

Comment: Yes, you can you `uax_url_email` tokenizer, but that will work for `emails` and  `urls` but for other string fields( which incude space and some special characters) ,you will still not be able to search for exact fields. Either you will have to make your fields `not_analyzed` or create your `custom analyzer` as per your requirements.